# scala functional quick sort

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming, quicksort

In the chapter 2 of the book http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf, M. Odersky wrote following implementation of quick sort

```
def sort(xs: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
 if (xs.length <= 1) xs
 else {
 val pivot = xs(xs.length / 2)
  Array.concat(
   sort(xs filter (pivot >)),
   xs filter (pivot ==),
   sort(xs filter (pivot <)))
 }
}
```

and said that "Both the imperative and the functional implementation have the same asymptotic
complexity – O(N log (N)) in the average case"
But it looks like not, because we apply filter predicate twice for partitioning array. In classical imperative version we are using one loop for array. So is running time for functional implementation O(N log (N)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quicksort and many other divide-and-conquer algorithms work by doing at most `O(n)` work for no more than `O(log(n))` passes over the data.  At each step we divide the data approximately in half, so that means we do indeed have only `log2(n)` passes through the data (one where it's not divided, one where it's divided approximately in half, etc.).

Then you just have to check that each pass through the data takes no more than `O(n)` time.  filter is `O(n)`, and we filter three times; plus `concat` is `O(n)` and we do it once.  Thus we do `4*O(n)` work, which is `O(n)`.

It's not the most efficient algorithm because of all the passes over the same data, but it is the right order.

Answer (score 4):

`filter` itself has O(n) and O(3n) = O(n), because the 3 is a constant factor. No matter, how large n is, filter will only be called 3 times.

**edit**: filter is called 3 times